# How to swipe panels between each other c#?

Tags: c#

I wrote the code so that I could move the controls(panels) in the main panel. I would like the controls(panels) not to overlap. I would like the controls(panels) to move as I add a new one between.

[image]

I would like to move blue panel(panel2) to down between red and gray panel but If i set `dock=TOP`, I can't move the controls.

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        INIT();
    }
    private Point firstPoint = new Point();
    private Point firstPoint2 = new Point();
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel2.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        panel3.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        panel4.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
    }

    public void INIT()
    {
        panel2.MouseDown += (ss, ee) => {
            if (ee.Button == MouseButtons.Left) firstPoint = Control.MousePosition;
        };

        panel2.MouseMove += (ss, ee) =>
        {
            if(ee.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                Point temp = Control.MousePosition;
                Point res = new Point(firstPoint.X - temp.X, firstPoint.Y - temp.Y);
                panel2.Location = new Point(panel2.Location.X - res.X, panel2.Location.Y - res.Y);
                firstPoint = temp;
            }
        };

        panel3.MouseDown += (ss, ee) => {
            if (ee.Button == MouseButtons.Left) firstPoint2 = Control.MousePosition;
        };

        panel3.MouseMove += (ss, ee) =>
        {
            if (ee.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                Point temp = Control.MousePosition;
                Point res = new Point(firstPoint2.X - temp.X, firstPoint2.Y - temp.Y);
                panel3.Location = new Point(panel3.Location.X - res.X, panel3.Location.Y - res.Y);
                firstPoint2 = temp;
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: I would put the three panels in to a main panel instead of directly into the form.  Then the color panels will move  better.

Comment: Colored panels are in panel(name: panelMain). i've got 4 panels(panelMain, panel2, panel3 and panel4)

Comment: The simple swap the top of the gray panel with top of blue panel : temp = panel2.Top panel2.Top = panel3.Top panel3.Top = Temp

Comment: I would like to do that with the mouse in runtime

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding your controls to the form, dock on of the Panel container  (maybe a [FlowLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/walkthrough-arranging-controls-on-windows-forms-using-a-flowlayoutpanel)) into your form, and add your controls to that.  Then you don't have to worry about positioning, the container will handle it.

Comment: I want to move panels by mouse

Comment: FlowLayoutPanel has very few properties and in the past did not give good results.  Used regular panel instead.